# Determining the name of the image file name after clicking on it

Tags: html, image

I'm working on a web application now, which would be hosting hundreds of images. Now, the images would be enclosed with anchor tags, like this:

```
<a href = "toss.html"><img src = "abc.png"></a>
```

Now, all the images would redirect to one common web page when clicked, i.e. toss.html. So is there a way wherein I can find the file name of the image I just clicked? Like in my above example, if I had clicked on the image, is there a way to determine the name of the file name 'abc.png' ? I would be needing the name of the image file for adding further features in my application.

EDIT:

Based on one of the answers mentioned below, I tried passing a GET parameter as follows: (I'm using Google App Engine with Python at backend)

```
<a href = "/test?file=CN.jpg"><img src = "/images/CN.jpg"></a>
```

This is the handler I defined:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(('/test', Test)], debug=True)

class Test(Handler):
    def get(self):
        f_name = self.request.get(file)
        self.response.write(f_name)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'FakeFile' has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: You could pass it as a parameter, as in `toss.html?f=abc.png`. But are you trying to do this without a server-side language? That doesn’t seem pleasant.

Comment: I'm using Python as my backend language.

Comment: So why would you want all images to go to one page, but do something different?

Comment: Because my application is an e-commerce site. And all my images will open in a common product template web page. And according to the image I click on, the template page would be different. And I have chosen to differentiate each product based on their image's file names.

Comment: Route a few things to the same template, then. Linking them all to the same page is not the right way to do it. http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: I have edited my original post. Please do have a look. I have passed on a parameter while defining the redirection link.

Comment: You passed the `file` function. Pass `'file'`, a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to pass the name of the image as a GET parameter to your landing page.  Then, your server that receives the request can read the parameters and create a different response depending on what's passed in.  For instance, to pass the GET parameter:

```
<a href="toss.html?img=abc"> <img src="abc.png"></a>
```

Depending on what backend framework you're using, you can access the page's get parameters in different ways before rendering a new page.  For instance, in php, you'd do something like this:

```
<?php
    $_GET["img"];
?>
```

If you have any other questions, post back below.

Comment: That was really helpful. However, how do I find the GET parameters in Python? I'm using the webapp2 framework in Google App Engine.

Comment: I have edited my original post. Please do have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have much experience with webapp2.  If I were debugging this though, I'd try a couple of things.  To distinguish whether the issue is with reading the get parameter or with your response.write, I'd still read into f_name using request.get, but then write a hardcoded value.  If this works, the problem is probably a type conversion with write.  Give it a shot and post back with the results.

Comment: Yeah, I found out the solution, keeping your answer as reference. Thanks a ton !